# Complexity of the following code fragment

Tags: time-complexity

I have to find the big O for the following piece of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) // O(n)
   if(n*f(i)+1>0)      // O(n*log(n))
     for(int j=f(i);j<n;j++) //O(n^2*log(n))
         g(j);               // O(n^3*log(n))
```

The O for function f is O(log(n)) and for the function g is O(n)

In the comments I've written my calculations  but not sure if they are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

[image]

Then the inner loop is (ignoring off-by-one):

[image]

Which is `O(n^2)` given that `i < n`.

Outer loop starting condition is 
[image], where `a` is some constant = the base of `log`. The exponent should be very small (though depends on the value of `lambda`), so the condition should be `<< n`.

Therefore the complexity is `O(n^3)`.